# Two related cells: give a value in one, calculate the other, and vice versa?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

How can I have a cell that uses the literal value written into it, or calculates its value when no literal value was given?

For example:

- I have two columns: column B with a price including VAT, and column C with a price without VAT.
- If I put a price with VAT in B2, then I want cell C2 to calculate the price without VAT based on B2.
- But if I put a price without VAT in C2, then I want cell B2 to calculate the price with VAT from C2.

[image: Excel table with some values]

I want to give this spreadsheet to my mother, who barely understands Excel. She just has to enter the values that she knows, and the worksheet should derive the other values from that.

Comment: @CharlieRB I tried putting the two formulas in each column, but then I get a circular reference because they reference each other. And when I overwrite such a formula cell with a literal value, I can't get the formula back when I remove the value. And I get warnings that my cells are inconsistent.

Comment: If you enter a value in column **C** what formula should be entered in column **B** ?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Given a value in column C, column B should calculate `=C2*1.20`. But given a value in column B, column C should calculate `=B2/1.20`.

Answer (score 0):

The following a a macro-based solution.  Put the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim BC As Range, t As Range, v As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Set t = Target
    Set BC = Range("B:C")
    If Intersect(t, BC) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        r = t.Row
        v = t.Value
        If v = "" Then
            Range("B" & r & ":C" & r).Value = ""
        End If
        If IsNumeric(v) Then
            If Intersect(t, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
                t.Offset(0, 1).Value = v * 1.2
            Else
                t.Offset(0, -1).Value = v / 1.2
            End If
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work**!